# How to count red blood cells/circles in Octave 3.8.2

Tags: image-processing, count, octave

I have an image with a group of cells and I need to count them. I did a similar exercise using bwlabel, however this one is a bit more challenging because there are some little cells that I don't want to count. In addition, some cells are on top of each other. I've seem some MATLAB examples online but they all involved functions that aren't available. Do you have any ideas how to separate the overlapping cells?

Here's the image:

[image: Erythrocytes]

To make it clearer: Please help me count the number of red blood cells (which have a circular shape) like so:

[image: Red blood cell]

The image is in grayscale but I think you can distinguish which ones are red blood cells. They have a distinctive biconcave shape... Everything else doesn't matter. But to be more specific here is an image with all the things that I want to ignore/discard/not count highlighted in red.

[image: Not to count]

The main issue is the overlapping of cells.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).It's difficult to know what you are trying to do if you are not telling us. For example, which ones are you trying to exclude? An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would tell us.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I need to count the number of red blood cells which are the bigger circles in the image. Some of them are on top of each other making the bwlabel function consider them as one object. Furthermore there are some little dots that I want to ignore. I was able to remove them using bwareaopen.

Comment: I dont really know how else to explain it... And I didn't include any code, because I already know why my strategy isn't working. I was hoping that someone would show me another way.

Comment: It doesn't help much, I'm afraid. Your question is not very well defined. You still have to show us. Add another image, for example highlight the ones you want to remove with a red circle manually or something.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an ImageJ macro to do this (which is free software too). I would recommend you use ImageJ (or Fiji), to explore this type of stuff. Then, if you really need it, you can write an Octave program to do it.

```
run ("8-bit");
setAutoThreshold ("Default");
setOption ("BlackBackground", false);
run ("Convert to Mask");
run ("Fill Holes");
run ("Watershed");
run ("Analyze Particles...", "size=100-Infinity exclude clear add");
```

This approach gives this result:

[image: screenshoot of the ROIs found]

And it is point and click equivalent as:

1. Image > Type > 8-bit
2. Image > Adjust > Threshold
3. select "Default" and untick "dark background" on the threshold dialogue. Then click "Apply".
4. Process > Binary > Fill holes
5. Process > Binary > Watershed
6. Analyze > Analyze particles...
   7 Set "100-Infinity" as range of valid particle size on the "Analyze particles" dialogue

On ImageJ, if you have a bianry image, watershed actually performs the distance transform, and then the watershed.

Octave has all the functions above except watershed (I plan on implementing it soon).

If you can't use ImageJ for your problem (why not? It can run in headless mode too), then an alternative is to get the area of each object, and if too high, then assume it's multiple cells. It kinda of depends on your question and if can generate a value for average cell size (and error).

Another alternative is to measure the roundness of each object identified. Cells that overlap will be less round, you can identify them that way.

It depends on how much error are you willing to accept on your program output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is for a university project which must be done using Octave. I was able to count 27 cells, but this is because there are four cells that are being lost in the overlapping areas.  I'm now trying to use regionprops 'Area' and 'Perimeter' to analyse them.

Comment: @r_laezza if you read my answer until the end, I also propose how to do it on Octave, but the exact code will be dependent on your needs and requires some pre-work. You will need an average cell size (and error), to identify possible duplets, in order to workaround not having watershed.

Answer (score 1):

This is only to help with "noise" but why not continue using bwlabel and try using `bwareaopen` to get rid of small objects? It seems the cells are pretty large, just set some size threshold to get rid of small objects http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46398-removing-objects-which-have-area-greater-and-lesser-than-some-threshold-areas-and-extracting-only-th

As for overlapping cells, maybe setting an upperbound for the size of a single cell. so when you have two cells overlapping, it will classify this as "greater than one cell" or something like that. so it at least acknowledges the shape, but can't determine exactly how many cells are there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was already using bwareaopen to that effect and it works well. However, using Octave, I still wasn't able to count the overlapping cells... I already found the area of the biggest cell (1238 pixels) and I was able to count the number of all the aggregates except for the one on the bottom right. I'm now trying to work both with area and perimeter to get better results.